# Why readdir() call in linux grows non-linearly

Tags: c, linux

I have a directory with 1000 files and `readdir()` takes less than 1 sec, but 10000 files take around 24 sec.

Why? It should be linear.

Can anyone explain the reason. 
And is there a better solution if only I need is to get the file and sub-directory names in a directory?

**EDIT**
I am on my local linux pc.

Comment: Why should it be linear? There are many things going on "under the hood": caching, networking (is a network drive?), other processes, etc. Not to mention things that might happen in your code (could you post that btw?)

Comment: But on which file system?

Comment: 1 second for 1000 files is quite a long time. **Something else is going on**. On a decent filesystem it should be better than linear, e.g. O(log N) or O(Sqrt(N)). Fat32 is O(N) (i.e. not a very good filesystem - lowest common denominator). NTFS is O(Log N). However I suspect you are actually looking at disk caching/prefetching. **Something else is going on.**

Comment: That kind of overhead? Hm. Sounds like somebody inserts the file names to an array, which is reallocated on every insert.

Comment: @Ben (and everyone else who says this) How can copying N items from the kernel to userland be better than O(N)? At best you can do some zero-copy scheme (which I've never seen any `readdir` use), that still only reduces the amount of work by a constant and you still end up with at least O(N). He's talking about `readdir`, not actually opening the files or doing `stat` on them (which I think is what actually goes on here).

Comment: @art because we are expecting disk access to dominate the time taken. If it was kernel activity 10000 items would be measured in milliseconds, not 24 seconds.

Comment: @Ben How do you expect the kernel to read fewer than O(N) data from the disk to read N directory entires?

Comment: @art, good point, it should be linear. O(Log N) is for seeks and updates.

Answer (score 3):

It might be file system specific. Perhaps using a suitably configured [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) or [BTRFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) file system should help. Some file systems are using hashing or B-tree techniques to make the complexity of file access in a directory of size *N* be *O(log N)*, others are still linear e.g. *O(N)*, and the kernel might do weird things above that.

The shell that you might use in your huge directories will generally sort entries when [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (see also [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)). And you don't want its [auto-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) to last many seconds on each keystroke!

I believe that you should *never* have huge directories (e.g. with more than a few hundred entries), so 10000 files in a single directory is unreasonable. If that is the case, you'll better organize your files differently, e.g. `subdir01/file001.txt` ... `sbudir99/file999.txt`

BTW, if your need is to have a lot of small things accessible by some textual key, using an indexed file (like [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/)) or a [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) "database", or a real database ([PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org), [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/) ...) is much more suitable, and probably more efficient. Don't forget to dump the data (probably in some textual format) for backup.

Notice that the documentation of [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) on Linux, and of POSIX [readdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) do not mention any time complexity or any linear behavior. This lack of mention is significant.
On the commonly used [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) filesystem (e.g. on many USB keys) the time complexity is probably quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

It has no reason to be linear. At lower level, a directory is like a file, a collection of clusters. If it is contained in one single cluster, you have only one actual physical read operation, the remaining occurs in memory. But when you directory becomes excessively large, you will have many physical reads. At this moment, as stated by Basile Starynkevitch, it becomes highly dependent on the file system structure.

But IMHO, if you want to browse the directory, it depends essentially on the number of clusters used by the directory. It is much more implementation dependant when you directly look for a file (by name) in a huge directory. Filsystems with linear search will have worse results than filesystems using natively hashing like for example BSD FFS.

Answer (score 0):

- All operations should be linear on a poor filesystem (e.g. FAT/FAT32 are `O(N)`).
- Seeks, updates and deletes should be better than linear on a good filesystem like NTFS which is `O(log N)`. A full directory listing will still be linear though.
- In either case it should be much, much faster than what you have reported in both the small and large cases.

I suspect something else is going on. Very likely your results are biased by other factors than the directory structure, such as:

- Disk has a hardware problem which is triggered in the large example but not the small one
- Other disk activity from other parts of the system interrupts the test in the large case
- Disk hardware pre-fetching. Disks contain RAM caches which will try to predict which sectors will be requested next, and have them ready.
- Operating system cache. Operating systems will also cache data in a similar way.
- You are possibliy doing something with the data other than just `readdir` and this other operation has higher time complexity which dominates.
- Your application memory usage pattern is able to fit into L1 cache for small directories but not large ones.
- Your application memory usage pattern forces swapping on large directories but not small ones.

Answer (score -1):

`readdir` is at best linear. If we ignore everything that goes on in the filesystem, the amount of data (file names and other stuff in struct dirent) from the kernel into userland is directly proportional to the number of files. So we start with O(n).

Then the kernel needs to figure out which data to give you. At best it is linearly stored in something that looks like a file. This is what older file systems like FFS and EXT2 do. This gives good performance for `readdir` (because finding which disk block to give you is just an array lookup), but has the disadvantage that actually opening those files (`open`, `stat` or almost anything else that works with the file name) becomes an O(n) operation because every open has to linearly scan the directory to find the file name. This is why there has been so much work in caching directory data for those file systems. Even on those filesystems you might end up seeing that larger directories take longer to read per item because the way file information is stored gets more expensive with file size. Depending on your file (or directory) size the kernel might need to read between 1 and 5 other blocks from disk (or cache) to find out which block to give you.

If you have a different filesystem (most modern ones), they trade the convenience and speed of a linear directory for a more complex structure on disk which gives you a much better performance of `open` and `stat` (after all, why would you `readdir` if you don't intend to do anything with the files?), but as a consequence you end up (not necessarily, but most likely) with worse than linear time to actually perform a `readdir` because the operation to find out which disk block to read for your information might be O(log n).